# spring boot, Not able to change the properties value at runtime using spring cloud config , @RefreshScope doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring cloud config to change the property value at runtime without restarting the app.

I have a repo which has different profiles and based on profile I have multiple apps running out of a single repo.

I have a service class with one of the @Profile annotation,

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Profile("change-feed")
@RefreshScope
public class ProcessorFeedService extends ProcessorService {

private final boolean toggle;
private final FeedPublisher publisher;

public ProcessorFeedService(FeedPublisher publisher,
                                           @Value("${feed.toggle}") boolean toggle) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.toggle = toggle;
}

public void handler(List<JsonNode> docs) {
    for (JsonNode document : docs) {
        try {
            if (toggle) {
                // do something
                publisher.publish();
            } else {
                // do something else
                inventoryChangePublisher.publish(document);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception occurred while processing {}", document.toString(), ex);
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

I have a "*application-change-feed*" properties file and one more *application-test* file in which(*application-test*) have this *feed.toggle* property value in cloud config repo.

application.properties file have these properties to enable the refresh endpoints and all

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,env,refresh,bindings
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.health.binders.enabled=true
spring.profiles.active=test
spring.profiles.include=change-feed
```

After changing the property value in cloud config file, hitting this refresh endpoint `https://{url}/actuator/refresh` it returns the changed property.
But it doesn't reflect the updated value in the application. Application picks the old one only.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh Scope usually works on classes annotated with `@Configuration`

From the spring documentation

[Spring Documentation](https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope)

Comment: I had @Configuration annotation but it still didn't work.